# Every nontrivial subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space has a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question from Finite-Dimensional Linear Algebra by Mark S. Gockenbach page 72 (exercise 2.7.12). I hope to check my proof.

> Prove that every nontrivial subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space has a basis.

My proof:

Suppose that $V$ is an $n-$dimensional vector space and let S be a nontrivial subspace of $V$.

Note that since $V$ is finite-dimensional and $S \subseteq V$, $S$ is also finite-dimensional.

Denote Dim($S$) = $m$ ($m \leq n$).

Since $V$ is an $n-$dimensional vector space, $\exists$ a basis $\{u_1,...,u_n \}$ for $V$.

By the definition, $\{u_1,...,u_n \}$ is linearly independent and it spans $V$.

Take $\{u_1,...,u_k \} \subseteq \{u_1,...,u_n \}$ ($1 \leq k \leq n$ ).

If $\{u_1,...,u_k \}$ spans $S$, then it is done.

If $S \subset \text{span}\{u_1,...,u_k \}$, we can discard some $u_i$'s and make $S = \text{span} \{u_1,...,u_l \}$ (and $l = m < k$).

If $\text{span}\{u_1,...,u_k \} \subset S$, $\exists$ $v_{k+1} \in S$ such that $v_{k+1} \notin \text{span} \{u_1,...,u_k \}$.

We can continue to add vectors $v_{k+2},...,v_l$ until there no longer exists a vector $v$ that does not belong to $\text{span}\{u_1,...,u_k,v_{k+1},...v_l \}$.

Now $\{u_1,...,u_k,v_{k+1},...v_l \}$ is linearly independent by construction and spans $S$ since there is no vector in $S$ that does not belong to $\text{span}\{u_1,...,u_k,v_{k+1},...v_l \}$.

By the definition, $\{u_1,...,u_k,v_{k+1},...v_l \}$ is a basis for $S$ (and $l=m$ must hold). $\blacksquare$

Comment: The trivial subspace also has a basis.

Comment: Wanted to comment the same thing. The empty set is a basis for the null vector space: it's linearly independent (vacuously true) and if you take the intersection of all subspaces that contain the emptyset, you get the null space. Hence, $span\emptyset = \{0\}$ and thus the emtyset is a basis.

Comment: Since you already seem to know that a subspace of a finite-dimensional space is also finite-dimensional, and that a finite-dimensional space has a basis, you can immediately conclude that $S$ is finite-dimensional and hence has a basis. Perhaps you actually need to prove that the subspace of a finite-dimensional space is also finite-dimensional, as it is not entirely obvious from $S \subseteq V$.